# Ordinary Differential Equation: Reduction to Homogeneous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve these 4 equations but I dont have idea how to proceed.

$$ (\sin x-\tan y+3)\cos x\,dx+(3\sin x+\tan y+1)\sec^2y\,dy=0 $$
$$ (\tan x-\cot y+3)\sec^2x\,dx-(3\tan x+\cot y+1)\csc^2y\,dy=0 $$
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\left[\frac{6x+4y-3}{3x+y-1}\right]^2-2\left[\frac{6x+4y-3}{3x+y-1}\right]$$
$$ y'=\left[\frac{2x-3y+4}{3x-2y-1}\right]^2 $$

I don't want the procedure, it's fine if only explain me how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

For the first two, you can use the variable transformation $\xi = \sin x, \eta = \tan y$ resp. $\xi = \tan x, \eta = -\cot y$. The third one is a bit more tricky: I found that if you introduce
\begin{equation}
 h(x) = \frac{6x+4y-3}{3x+y-1},
\end{equation}
then the ODE for $h$ is
\begin{equation}
 (6x-1) h' = (h-1)(h-2)(h-3)(h-4),
\end{equation}
which should help. A similar trick, involving the introduction of
\begin{equation}
 k(x) = \frac{2x-3y+4}{3x-2y-1},
\end{equation}
transforms the fourth ODE to
\begin{equation}
(11-5x) k' = (k+1)(k-2)(2k-3)(2k-1).
\end{equation}
In the last two equations, you can use a variable transformation $x \to \xi(x)$ to get rid of the $x$-dependent terms multiplying the left hand sides, since
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} x} = \frac{\text{d} \xi}{\text{d} x} \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} \xi}.
\end{equation}
I hope this gives you enough ideas to proceed!

Comment: How do you transform the fourth ODE from the second trick?

Comment: What do you mean? How to obtain the ODE for $k$, or how to choose $\xi(x)$ such that the ODE becomes autonomous?

Comment: How do you obtain the ODE for $k$  ??

Comment: Well, the same way you obtain the ODE for $h$: take the derivative of $k$ and substitute the original ODE for $y'$. Also, write $y$ in terms of $k$ and $x$, and use that to obtain the ODE for $k$. I would strongly advice you try this yourself, and see where it takes you. Should you become stuck somewhere, post your efforts here and I'm sure someone can help you out.